# Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript

I am using this code to iterate through a custom object:

```
interface TableItemBody {
    [fieldId: string]: string
}

interface TableItem {
    [tabId: string]: TableItemBody | TableItemBody[]
}

const iterate = (entry: TableItem) => {
    for (const tabId of Object.keys(entry)) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry[tabId])) {
            for (const idx of entry[tabId]) {
                for (const fieldId of Object.keys(entry[tabId][idx])) {
                    console.log(fieldId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (const fieldId of Object.keys(entry[tabId])) {
                console.log(fieldId)
            }
        }
    }
}

const tableItem: TableItem = {
    tab1: {
        field1: 'fieldValue'
    },
    tab2: [{
        field2: 'fieldValue'
    }]
}

iterate(tableItem)
```

However, I am getting two errors. The first one is `Type 'TableItemBody | TableItemBody[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` I am using `Array.isArray(entry[tabId])` to ensure that I am actually iterating through an array. So why does this error appear?

If you want to play with that code, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwEYBsIElIC2AQgPYAmAnsgN4BQyDyA2jMBFmbmQFzIDOYKKADmAXV4ChIYbQC+tWqEixEKdNjyEa9RkzCYuEwSPFpMOfBGLkqAHzMbL1yk1FyFCEiAHJgyuJDIALzIABQQ4FAUvOoWhACUwQB82ozIMCRQYZ7eYMj6GFzIJDDIAPIYAFYQCGAAdADWEBR84ZEU8Yl0aWnApaEAglBQcBR1wHxDIxRtghR6BmSinak9axlZoTk+wGQAHsWlEXMLhUtdOmtX6ZnZXj6s7Jxkh+VVNfVNLbNRp1yiTF2e2WF2uYMY2xIODqWBIwlCjw4XHil3BjHkaOQGKusmQ7D4KG6aI2d1y6TYSJeJTe1VqjWarWOvwK-xWRMxDEh0Nh8MRzxRmOxayFWPctG2eQKcSsMXMmiswVWDAKAEZeOyeny1cgAOR8gBqcCwAFcIDrUbIADSogoAJl4TA1aT59t1BqNpvNaVkbnkin8kFCUvlBHiQA) is the link the to typescript playground.

Comment: try `const en = entry[tabId];` and use `en` afterward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it to `TableItemBody[]`. Look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwEYBsIElIC2AQgPYAmAnsgN4BQyDyA2jMBFmbmQFzIDOYKKADmAXV4ChIYbQC%20tWqEixEKdNjyEa9RkzCYuEwSPFpMOfBGLkqAHzMbL1yk1FyFCEiAHJgyuJDIALzIABQQ4FAUvOoWhACUwQB82ozIMCRQYZ7eYMj6GFzIJDDIAPIYAFYQCGAAdADWEBR84ZEU8Yl0aWnApaEAglBQcBR1wHxDIxRtghR6BmSinak9azk%20BXFWfMHIEXMLhUvIcLuxmlakLm5raxlZoRt5W5cExaWvTnxdOnd3D2yXh8rHYnDIH3KVRq9SaLVCXwSv3%20KMYGxIODqWBIwlCoI4XHif1RjHkJOQZLusn2WD4KG6JMBT2BeXx4MhFWqtUazVaByiRy4y2R5LRwIxECxOLxbAJZCJ5MpayVFPctGe%20XMbxiWqcewZDAKAEZeAaemyTcgAORsgBqcCwAFcIFbibIADTEgoAJl4TDNaTZvutdodztdaVkbnkin8kARuoSQA)

```js
const iterate = (entry: TableItem) => {
    for (const tabId of Object.keys(entry)) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry[tabId])) {
            const tableItems = entry[tabId] as TableItemBody[]
            for (const tableItem of tableItems) {
                for (const fieldId of Object.keys(tableItem)) {
                    console.log(fieldId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (const fieldId of Object.keys(entry[tabId])) {
                console.log(fieldId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I thought typescript would automatically find out that it is an array because I checked that with `Array.isArray`, but apparently I was wrong.